Can we use Gauss-Seidel method in a not invertable matrix?
When studying Gauss-Seidel method in wikipedia, I found a problem.
Given a matrix equation AX=b, and let A be a n x n matrix, X and b be n x 1 matrix. Also, A and b are known; X is unknown.
I was wonder if A is not an invertable matrix, can we still apply Gauss-Seidel method?

This is discussed at  wikipedia. Did you see it?

Oh I see it, thanks.

If the matrix is diagonally dominant or positive definite then Gauss Seidel converges. In both cases, the matrix is invertible because no eigenvalue is zero.

The actual implications are reversed... For instance, if the matrix is strictly diagonally dominant then Gauss-Seidel method converges. But it can also converge if the matrix is not diagonally dominant.
